# How to find the pid file of circusd?

Tags: python, linux, monit, circusd

I am running circusd for my python's service and want to use monit for the same. Hence, I need to know the pid file in order to monitor circusd. All I can see in the `ps aux` command is Python processes but no sign of Circusd. Is the daemon under the hood and runs the Python programs as instructed by my confg file of circusd? Or can I see whether circusd is among the running processes?

How do I know where is the pid file of circusd? Is it possible to achieve this aim of getting the pid file of circusd via python?

Note: I am using Linux(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: is circusd not in programming scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the pid file , follow the below:

1. login as root
2. type the command as below to find all pid files in your server
   find / -name *.pid

Moreover, if you want to check specific process and you don't have it is pid file, you can use matchproc to match the process instead of using it pid file or you have to create a pid file manually .

You can refer to this below example:

## Monitor vsftpd

check process vsftpd  matching vsftpd
if failed port 21 protocol ftp then alert